# Ruby Windows script with Win32API

Tags: ruby, windows, ocra

**Done**

I have written a ruby script to capture key presses and print those in file

Code is similar to this

https://github.com/bgnash/kopykat/blob/master/kopykat.rb

I have used ocra to make window service

http://abstractcoder.com/2013/08/02/create-a-windows-service-with-ruby-part-2.html

**After completion**

When I register this service in windows , service is running but nothing get printed in file

**Alternative**

Now I made the exe version of script and again tested in windows now I can see printed key presess names in the file

**Issue to fix**

I want to run this script in service with working state. Any help??

**MY SIMPLE QUESTION IS CAN WE USE WIN32API IN WINDOWS SERVICE**

Comment: You'll want to [edit] your question to follow the guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -- specifically, explain exactly what you want to happen, what's actually happening, and include a [mcve] _in the question itself_

Comment: @QPaysTaxes As you can see All details are there code sample is there what elde you think should be added?

Comment: Please read my comment before responding to it. The whole comment. Every last bit of it. Including the last four words.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Yes I did

Comment: Then you should know that linking to your code isn't enough. Read the second link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I came up with solution that in running service we can't get benefit of WINAPI, So for I have to use dotnet wrapper (tray app) to run my ruby exe and its running in the Tray, And guess but it is running awesome..